# Common If Structure

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic

More and more I find myself writing a structure of If statements that looks like this:

```
if(something) {
  if(somethingElse) {
     // If both evaluate to true.
     doSomething();
  }
  else {
     // If the first if is true but the second is not.
     doSomethingElse();
  }
}
else {
     // If the first evaluates the false.
     doSomethingDifferent();
}
```

Now, to me, this looks horrific. Does anyone have a cleaner way of representing this logic?

Comment: While it looks terrible, it is very easy to debug.

Comment: I suspect you mean `doSomethingElse()` and `doSomethingElse2()` (i.e., 3 different subroutines instead of 2)?

Comment: I do apologise. @Ioannis That's exactly what I mean. It's been a long day at work. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: I would wrap it in a subroutine (would probably call it `nestedIfs(doSomething, doSomethingElse, doSomethingDifferent`)

Comment: Agreed. That's how I make the code tidier, but I was wondering if there was any way of tidying up this actual tree, rather than the code that uses it?

Comment: That looks fine but not so interesting.  A more interesting scenario to ask about would be if code is required between testing the conditions `something` and `somethingElse`, but if the actions marked `doSomethingElse` and `doSomethingDifferent` were in fact the same.  I end up with that pattern a fair amount, and the only way I've found to avoid duplicating the `doSomethingELse`/`doSomethingDifferent` is to use a (hiding) `goto`.  Not that such a control-flow statement is elegant, but if the common action cannot very well be factored out into its own method, is apt to change, and...

Comment: @Chris Probably not, in terms of logic, as there are 3 clauses and 3 actions that have to be represented explicitly, assuming that they are different..

Comment: ...will cause hard-to-find bugs if the two copies of it are accidentally changed inconsistently, using such a control-flow statement to avoid code duplication might be the least-evil possibility.  I wish there were statement-level equivalents of `&&` and `||`, but unless one is using a gcc variant where parenthesis-enclosed statements are regarded as expressions, there aren't.

Comment: @Chris: With regard to your particular code, if you need all three actions different, you could perhaps reverse the condition of the first `if`: `if (!something) doSomethingDifferent; else if (somethingElse) doSomething; else doSomethingElse;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as-is has three cases: `something & somethingelse`, `something & !somethingelse`, and `!something`. The alternative is to break it out into an if-else with three branches:

```
if(something & somethingElse) {
     // If both evaluate to true.
     doSomething();
  }
elif(something) { // explicit test of somethingElse falsity not required
     // If the first if is true but the second is not.
     doSomethingElse();
  }
else {
     // If the first evaluates the false.
     doSomethingDifferent();
}
```

For such a simple case, I usually prefer to flatten the structure as above. For more complex cases, it can end up being simpler to nest, or even better to reduce your tests to some kind of structure (a list or integer depending on your language) and switch on that value.